# Temporarily suspend the PC operating system

Tags: windows, linux, suspend

How does one programmatically cause the OS to switch off, go away and stop doing anything at all so that a program may have complete control of a PC system?

I'm interested in doing this from both an MS Windows and Linux environments.  Any languages or APIs considered.

I want the OS to stop preempting my program, stop its virtual memory management, stop its device drivers and interrupt service routines from running and basically just go away.  Then, when my program has had its evil way with the bare metal, I want the OS to come back again without a reboot.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  The only reason I can think of is to mess around with things that you shouldn't otherwise be messing around with (Flash BIOS, etc...).

Comment: I accept that the use-case is vanishingly small. My interest is primarily performance.  This sort of thing used to be routine in the old 8 & 16-bit days and I think it has value as an intellectual exercise.  I thought perhaps that the OS vendors had exerted enough pressure on chip vendors to add OS support hardware that would make this impossible, but that human ingenuity would find some sneaky ways around the prohibitions.  Some interesting answers here.

Comment: You'd have to be *real* careful not to step on anything that would cause problems when the OS came back.  Any reason you can't reboot into a custom OS and reboot into the original one?  Performance seems an odd reason for something you'd almost never do.

Answer (score 14):

With Linux, you could use [kexec jump](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/linux-kernel/2007/7/11/114296/thread) to transfer control completely to another kernel (ie, your program). Of course, with great power comes great responsibility - it is entirely up to you to service interrupts, and avoid corrupting the old kernel's memory. You'll end up having to write your own OS kernel to do this. Also, the transfer of control takes quite some time, as the kernel has to de-initialize all hardware, then reinitialize it when it's time to resume. Since kexec jump was originally designed for hibernation support, this isn't a problem in its original context, but depending on what you're doing, it might be a problem.

You may want to consider instead working within the framework given to you by the OS - just write a normal driver for whatever you're doing.

Finally, one more option would be using the linux [Real-Time patchset](http://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page). This lets you assign static priorities to everything, even interrupt handlers; by running a process with higher priority than anything else, you could suspend /nearly/ everything - the system will still service a small stub for interrupts, as well as certain interrupts that can't be deferred, like timing interrupts, but for the most part the heavy work will be deferred until you relinquish control of the CPU.

Note that the RT patchset won't stop virtual memory and the like - [mlockall](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_mlockall.htm) will prevent page faults on valid pages though, if that's enough for you.

Also, keep in mind that whatever you do, the system BIOS can still cause [SMM traps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Mode), which cannot be disabled, except by motherboard-model-specific methods.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of really ugly ways to do this.  You could modify the running kernel by writing some trampoline code to /dev/kmem that passes control to your application.  But I wouldn't recommend attempting something like that!

Basically, you would need to have your application act as its own operating system.  If you want to read data from a file, you would have to figure out where the data lives on disk, and generate your own SCSI requests to talk to the disk drive.  You would have to implement your own interrupt handler to get notified when the data is ready.  Likewise you would have to handle page faults, memory allocation, etc.  Most users feel that this isn't worth the effort...

Why do you want to do this?

Is there something that your application needs to do that the OS won't let it do?  Are you concerned with the OS impact on performance?  Something else?

Comment: There are legitimate reasons to want to do something like this. For instance, to get dependable hard-realtime response from the system. See my answer below.

Comment: I agree that if you want real-time response, you will want to get Windows (or Linux) "out of the way."  But I would still argue that the sane way to achieve that is to run a real-time operating system (or executive) between the hardware are the application, rather than having the application completely take over the HW.  If that's what the OP is after, I agree that the RTX approach is a good one.  (FWIW, years ago I worked for VenturCom, whose technology is now part of IntervalZero's RTX...)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind shelling out some cash, you could use [IntervalZero's RTX](http://www.intervalzero.com/rtx.htm) to do this for a Windows system. It's a hard realtime subsystem that gets installed on a Windows box as sort of a hack into the HAL and takes over the machine, letting Windows have whatever CPU cycles are left over.

It has its own scheduler and device drivers, but if you run your program at the top RTX priority, don't install any RTX device drivers (or disable interrupts for the duration), then *nothing* will interrupt it.

It also supports a small amount of interaction with programs on the Windows side.

We use it as a nice way to get a hard realtime box that runs Windows.

Answer (score 2):

[coLinux](http://www.colinux.org/) loads `CoLinuxDriver` into the NT kernel or a `colinux.ko` into the Linux kernel.  It does exactly what you asked – it "unschedules" the host OS, and runs its own code, with its own memory management, interrupts, etc.  Then, when it's done, it "reschedules" the host OS, allowing it to continue from where it left off.  coLinux uses this to run a modified Linux kernel parallel to the host OS.

Unlike more common virtualization techniques, there are no barriers between coLinux and the bare metal hardware at all.  However, hardware and the host OS tend to get confused if the coLinux guest touches anything without restoring it before returning to the host OS.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. Operating Systems are a foundation, and your program runs on top of them. The OS handles memory access, disk writing operations, communications, etc. when your application makes requests, and asking the OS to move out of the way would mean that your program would have to do the OS's job instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not as such, no.

What you want is basically an application that becomes an OS; a severely stripped down Linux kernel coupled with some highly customized and minimized tools might be the way to go for this.

Comment: Not impossible; it's been done, as a variant of hibernation. See my post. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you were devious, and wanted to avoid alot of the operating system housekeeping you could probably hook yourself into a driver routine.  Thinking out aloud, verging on hacking.  google how to write root kits.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah dude, you can totally do that, you can also write a program to tell my bank to give you all my money and send you a hot Russian.

Comment: what's not funny about this people!

Comment: You unwittingly happened upon my very idea, damn you!

Comment: +1: I'll show ya' some love!  :)  -2 seemed harsh for an obvious joke.  :)